# Generating cheap perfect outlines for meshes in WebGL

Tags: opengl, rendering, webgl

I am tasked with creating an outline shader in WebGL (i'm using WASM/Emscripten, so an OpenGL solution will work too) for meshes that the user can upload into our software (be it .obj, .fbx, .3ds), basically a clone of how [sketchup](https://www.sketchup.com/) does their outlines on meshes. Where the user can also control the thickness of the outlines with a slider. So, I basically have a vertex buffer, index buffer, the associated textures, and uv coordinates.

My first try at this problem was creating a sobel edge detector on both the depth buffer and a buffer containing the normals of each fragment in the GLSL shaders using a post processing pass, in order to detect edges. And then the slider just controls the threshold value. However the thresholding doesn't seem to work generically for all meshes that a user can upload (especially if the mesh doesn't have smooth normals, like the threshold value will work for one mesh, but not another) and the number of bits in the depth buffer doesn't seem to be great when working with WebGL/JS. I learned my first approach from [GPU Gems](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems2/part-ii-shading-lighting-and-shadows/chapter-15-blueprint-rendering-and-sketchy).

So I am looking for a better solution. Something that is more robust.

In my research I have found some repos in unreal engine 4 that use vertex colors to achieve the task. Where they assign a vertex color for every vertex that is part of the same face (so multiple tris can have the same vertex color). But that seems like something an artist would have to do themselves, not really computer generated. These are the repos [1](https://github.com/chrisloop/UE4_Vertex_Color_Edges) and [2](https://github.com/chrisloop/HDRPVertexColorEdges). Another approach I though about is generating a wireframe mesh for the faces of the mesh in question (not the tris of the mesh, but the faces). But it then comes back to the problem of discovering what the faces of the mesh are.

I also read this page here [3](https://alexanderameye.github.io/notes/rendering-outlines/). But all the other methods don't seem to give nice internal outlines like edge detection has done. Here are some other resources I have read [4](https://bgolus.medium.com/the-quest-for-very-wide-outlines-ba82ed442cd9) and [5](https://www.videopoetics.com/tutorials/pixel-perfect-outline-shaders-unity/) and [6](http://xroft666.blogspot.com/2015/07/glow-highlighting-in-unity.html).

Any suggestions would be a massive help, thank you!

Comment: The jump flooding technique (also sometimes called the distance transform) doesn't have to be used on a solid background (number 4 in the links from the post). For example it can be combined with basic image edge detection to create outlines of any thickness.  The edge detection output becomes the jump flood input.